# How to add a sub-field from JSON into Google Sheets using Google Sheets app script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, mapping, destructuring

```
function import_inventory_test(e) {
  var options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Prefer': 'code=200',
      'Prefer': 'dynamic=true',
      "clientId": "1",
      "key": "1",
        }
      }
      var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://stoplight.io/mocks/flowhub/public-developer-portal/24055485/v0/inventory?max=100", options).getContentText();
      var json = JSON.parse(text);
    
  
   var values = json.data.map(({ sku, quantity, productName, brand }) => [sku, quantity, productName, brand]);
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

1. how can I add to the "json.data.map" the "gramAmount" which is under "weightTierInformation":

```
     "weightTierInformation": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "gramAmount": 0,
          "pricePerUnitInMinorUnits": 0
        }   ]
```

2. How can I store the fields names in a "var" so I won't have to write them in 2 different locations? X=>X

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this? @Tanaike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var values = json.data.map(({ sku, quantity, productName, brand }) => [sku, quantity, productName, brand]);
```

#### To:

In this case, all rows are filled by `sku, quantity, productName, brand, gramAmount`.

```
var values = json.data.flatMap(({ sku, quantity, productName, brand, weightTierInformation }) =>
  weightTierInformation.map(({gramAmount}) => [sku, quantity, productName, brand, gramAmount])
);
```

Or, in the following case, each 1st row has `sku, quantity, productName, brand, gramAmount`, and other rows have `null, null, null, null, gramAmount`.

```
var values = json.data.flatMap(({ sku, quantity, productName, brand, weightTierInformation }) =>
  weightTierInformation.map(({gramAmount}, j) => j == 0 ? [sku, quantity, productName, brand, gramAmount] : [...Array(4).fill(null), gramAmount])
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you are the man! but I do have a question, I like the first version of the script you created because it won't create empty rows but it does duplicate the rows, is there a way to convert those extra 3 rows into columns? @Tanaike

Comment: Without predetermining it will split the data into an exact number of columns so it can be used for dynamic data @Tanaike

Comment: @Kal El Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your actual expected result from `but it does duplicate the rows, is there a way to convert those extra 3 rows into columns?` and `Without predetermining it will split the data into an exact number of columns so it can be used for dynamic data`. Can I ask you about the detail of your actual expected result? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Your English is great! I'm sorry I didn't explain myself correctly! thank you very much for the script! I will create a new question and I will try to explain it better and give some examples! thanks again! @Tanaike

Comment: @Kal El Thank you for replying. I understood it. When I saw your new question, I would like to check it.